# Adding Page Numbering in a Word document C# starting from given Page number

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

It's been 8 hours since i'm stuck here. I want ask user to input a page number and starting from the given page it should add page numbering till the .docx file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string fileName;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void minimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx";
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            fileName = dlg.FileName;
            textBox1.Text = fileName;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

On button2_click i want to update the file by using data from a textBox2, can anybody complete it?

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't even see you referencing "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" outside of importing it.  Also note: using Interops will require a Microsoft license on the machine that runs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't complete it, but I will point you in the right direction. You have to have a reference to Microsoft Word. What you are trying to do is typically referred to as automation or more specifically Microsoft Word Automation.

You can google that and find examples or try this location for starting point.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I needed it badly, there are some other questions that i'd like to ask, can we load a saved document and change something in it? Every example i see, they start from scratch and they have never loaded something saved.

Comment: There is a great deal of functionality in  Word itself that you probably should explore. For example Templates (Provide a document starting point), also Footers would allow you to start numbering pages on a certain page. I would get a good book on Word and explore what it can do out of the box. That being said, just about anything a user could do or a word macro can do you can do through automation. Same applies to Microsoft Excel, Outlook, etc.  Just google with the right phrases, such as: "word start page numbering on certain page", don't include the quotes. You will probably find it.